# Rails callback before_validation not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I got this code from rails guides and i think this code is not working as if `title` is blank than it should has the value of `body` but its not working this way instead it shows error "Title can't be blank". Apology if its too simple question.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :body, presence: true

  before_validation :ensure_title_has_a_value

  protected
  def ensure_title_has_a_value
    if title.nil?
        self.title = body unless body.blank?
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine your title attribute is not actually `nil`, especially if it is coming from a form.  It is probably just an empty string.

Try changing your validation to:

```
def ensure_title_has_a_value
  if title.blank?
    self.title = body unless body.blank?
  end
end
```